# Silverlight: How to bind to parent view's DataContext?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a ParentView that contains a childView

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="MyParentView">
     <Grid>
        <sdk:TabControl Name="ContactTabControl">
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Contact" Name="CustomerTabItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Views:CustomerView/>
                </Grid>
            </sdk:TabItem>
        </sdk:TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Within my CustomerView I would like to bind the Firstname textbox to Parent's DataContext. I have tried this inside the CustomerView:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=MyParentView, Path=DataContext.Firstname} />
```

I have the feeling that CustomerView won't be able to see its parent at all, hence the ElementName "MyParentView" would never be found.

What is your advice on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a similar thing but I just bound it directly to Path considering that if I don't give it explicit data context, it will lookup the hierarchy and find one that matches.

So this should get you what you want:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=FirstName} />
```

if you need to specify explicit datacontext you can always do:

```
<Grid>
    <Views:CustomerView DataContext={"CustomContextHere"}/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to Maverik's is :

1 Define a dependency property in your customer view :

```
public partial class CustomerView : UserControl
    {
        public CustomerView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerView), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, CustomerView.FirstNameChanged));

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void FirstNameChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        { }
    }
```

2 Modify the customer view's textbox to bind to this dependency property (note the element binding "this")

```
<UserControl x:Class="SLApp.CustomerView"
    x:Name="this"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="400" Height="300">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, ElementName=this, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid> </UserControl>
```

3 Modify the parent view and bind it's DataContext to the new dependency property

```
<sdk:TabControl Name="ContactTabControl">
                        <sdk:TabItem Header="Contact" Name="CustomerTabItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <local:CustomerView FirstName="{Binding ElementName=ContactTabControl, Path=DataContext}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </sdk:TabItem>
                    </sdk:TabControl>
```

4 Set the parent's DataContext

```
public partial class MyParentView : UserControl
    {
        public MyParentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ContactTabControl.DataContext = "A name";
        }
    }
```

Voila' it works. Not the most elegant solution but it gets the job done for your scenario

Comment: Thanks for this example. i think its valuable since I can see for the first time a dependency property in action. :) Since MVVM was introduced there is little use for these. But its good to knwo for interviews. +1